# $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if it maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence, continuity, metric-spaces

**The Problem**: $f:X\to Y$ is continuous if it maps convergent sequences to convergent sequences.

Note the condition is NOT equivalent to the following: if $(x_n)\subset X$ converges to $x\in X$ then $(f(x_n))\subset Y$ converges to $f(x)\in Y$. The assumption is that $(x_n)\to x\in X\implies (f(x_n))\to y$ for SOME $y\in Y$.

**My Attempt**: Obviously we want to show that given the same sequence $(x_n)\subset X$ as above, then that "SOME" $y\in Y$ is indeed $=f(x)$. Proof by contradiction did not seem to work. I understand that I must make use of the arbitrariness of the "convergent sequences" in the statement, but could not quite figure out how.

Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hint: if $(x_n)$ converges to $x$, then so does $x_1, x, x_2, x, x_3, x, \ldots$.

Comment: @TheoBendit Beautiful. Thank you so much!